# Add a cover page to a PDF document

Tags: pdf, merge, cover

I create a PDF document with EVO PDF library from a HTML page using the code below:

```
HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
byte[] outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrl(url);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=Merge_HTML_with_Existing_PDF.pdf; size={0}", outPdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));
Response.BinaryWrite(outPdfBuffer);
Response.End();
```

This produces a PDF document but I have another PDF document that I would like to use as cover page in the final PDF document.

One possiblity I was thinking about was to create the PDF document and then to merge my cover page PDF with the PDF produced by converter but this looks like an inefficient solution. Saving the PDF and loading back for merge seems to introduce a unnecessary overhead. I would like to merge the cover page while the PDF document produced by converter is still in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line added in your code right after you create the HTML to PDF converter object should do the trick:

```
// Set the PDF file to be inserted before conversion result
htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.AddStartDocument("CoverPage.pdf");
```

Comment: I can't believe. It works !!!!!! But I now I have one more problem :-). I have footer in my PDF document created by HTML to PDF converter where I show the page numbers. This footer does not appear in the cover page ...

Comment: Glad to hear it works. The header and footer are not added by default in external PDFs you merge with HTML to PDF conversion result, but you can enable the footer in the cover page if you add  the following parameters to AddStartDocument function : 'htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.AddStartDocument("CoverPage.pdf", true, true, true)'.

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm now. I think this is all I needed !!!! You've been of great help !!!!